# Why a well running view gets zero values in the native bounding box in Geoserver?

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, postgis, geoserver

I am working on a remote db and I have all privileges as a user. I have created a spatial relational db that consists of 5 tables and one of them has the geometry column. When I'm trying to publish only the table with the geometry which has srid GGRS87, EPSG:2100, the native bbox is computing well but when I'm trying to create a view either from PostGIS or via Geoserver, the Native BBox gives values (-1,-1,0,0) and also the Lat/Lon BBox doesn't have the correct ones.The view in the db runs correctly, merging all the 5 tables.Lastly, I notice that when I create the view via Geoserver, the column of SRID doesn't show up to set it from there.

What could be possibly go wrong with the connection between PostGIS and Geoserver or it is sth else?
Thanks!

```html
CREATE VIEW buildings AS
SELECT 
  id_owner,id_building,address_name,address_num,
  region,x,y,closing_file
FROM owner
JOIN owner_property 
  ON owner.id_owner = owner_property.owner_id
JOIN building 
  ON property.building_id=building.id_building;
```

Comment: Can you also provide the data? At least one geometry, so that we test with real data :)

Comment: Like @JimJones mention it would be useful to have more data, like the sql view you are using in GeoServer. For what I see both fields x and y are double so it make no sense to have SRID, in other words there is no geometry field.

Comment: @Newstudent which of the columns in your `select` correspond to the geometry? Or you just have `x` and `y`?

Comment: From x,y columns, I 've created the geometry column.Picture above.

Comment: @Newstudent alright. But I don't see this geometry you created in the `SELECT` posted above. Have you tried instead of simply writing `SELECT x,y ..` you do `SELECT ST_MakePoint(x,y,2100) ..`. and try to publish again

Comment: @Jim Jones You are absolute right! It only understood x,y columns without having literally the geometry column. In the view query, I added ST_MakePoint (x,y,2100) instead of x,y and now it works !! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view seems to have no geometry, and consequently no SRS. You most likely forgot to insert it into your view or, as your screenshot suggests, the coordinate pairs are split into two columns - `x` and `y`. So just use `ST_MakePoint` with `x` and `y` in the query used to create the view ..

```
CREATE VIEW buildings_reinspection_file AS
SELECT 
  id_owner,id_building,address_name,address_num,
  region,inspection_num,reinspection_num,reinspection_date,
  approval_num,ownership_perc,building_assessm,color_tagged,
  construction_type,ST_MakePoint(x,y,2100),closing_file
FROM owner
JOIN owner_property 
  ON owner.id_owner = owner_property.owner_id
JOIN property 
  ON owner_property.property_id = property.id_property
JOIN building 
  ON property.building_id=building.id_building
JOIN financial_assist 
  ON property.financial_assist_id=financial_assist.id_financial_assist;
```

.. and try to publish it again in GeoServer. If the column you created in the table `building` containing the geometry is called `point`, just replace the `ST_MakePoint(x,y,2100)` by `building.point`.

Comment: As I mentioned, if I try to publish only the table with the geometry (building)(point), the computing of the native bbox is successful! I see all the points in the preview layer. My csv file had x,y coordinates from which I have created the geometry column (point geometry(Point,2100)). And also when I create the view, the merging of 5 tables is correct including the geometry.

Comment: Why I have to insert the geometry in the view when the view displays a complex select from five tables, one of which has the geometry column and it shows all the data and the geometry in the correct way.